# Implementing Live Reloading for WordPress and Vue Development on Localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, frontend, browser-sync

I am currently developing a **Vue** application as a **WordPress** theme and need to establish communication between **WordPress** and **Vue** using **PHP**. To achieve this, I need to run both the **WordPress server** and **Vue app** simultaneously on my **localhost**. However, I have encountered an issue where the **WordPress server** does not have **live reloading** functionality when modifying **Vue** files. In order to address this problem, I have explored potential solutions and would like to confirm if my approach is correct.

To address the issue of live reloading on the **WordPress server** while making changes to **Vue** files, I have implemented the following approach. **Firstly**, I run separate **local servers** for both **WordPress** and **Vue**. Additionally, I set up another local server using **Browsersync**, which acts as a **proxy** for the **WordPress server**. This **Browsersync server** monitors the **Vue** files for any modifications and triggers a reload whenever changes are detected.

While this solution has proven effective in providing live reloading functionality for the **Vue app**, I would appreciate your professional opinion on whether this approach aligns with best practices or if there are alternative methods that may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a proxy like this does work - but it causes *everything* to be proxied which is a bit extreme if all you want is live-reloading.

Browsersync has 'snippet mode' + 'localOnly' for this.

For example, you can run

```bash
browser-sync start --files 'app/**/*.php' --localOnly
```

Which will output the following in your terminal

```
$ browser-sync start --files 'app/**/*.php' --localOnly
[Browsersync] Copy the following snippet into your website, just before the closing </body> tag
<script async id="__bs_script__" src="http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.29.2"></script>
```

So, copy the HTML snippet into any PHP template or HTML file and you'll get live-reloading etc

https://gist.github.com/shakyShane/d2d12070b1c9b6c56e7ef3403e872de7